# Amazon ec2 is not responding over http on port 8088

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a java process that is listening on port 8088

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9991          :::*                    LISTEN      11189/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      11189/java
```

And I can get a response with wget locally:

```
 wget http://54.xxx.xxx.13:8088/admin/login
--2014-02-20 11:18:53--  http://54.xxx.xxx.13:8088/admin/login
Connecting to 54.xxx.xxx.13:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1991 (1.9K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘login.5’

100%[============================================================================================================>] 1,991       --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-02-20 11:18:53 (138 MB/s) - ‘login.5’ saved [1991/1991]
```

But then it doesn't respond when I try it in the browser. Why not? I have set the correct security in the aws console and port 80 and port 8080 are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall may be blocking inbound traffic to the instance. Modify the instance security group to permit inbound tcp/8088 traffic.

Details of how to modify security groups can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule).

Comment: I did it already and it worked this morning over HTTP on port 8088. I don't know what caused this now. Port 8080 is listening and I opened port 8088 same way.

Comment: Is there a firewall on your network or PC that's blocking outbound traffic to 8088?

Comment: Actually, looking at your netstat output it appears that your server is only listening on the loopback interface - it probably should be listening on all interfaces (like the sshd is above - 0.0.0.0:22)

Comment: I don't understand. I did nothing wrong and it worked this morning and now I opened all the ports and still it won't respond.

Comment: If I change the port to 8080 then it responds. It's only if I try and use port 8088 that it's b0rked and there is no reason for that. I don't understand how this can be possible.

Comment: Shutdown your server on port 8088. Then run the following netcat command on your AWS instance: "nc -l 8088". Then try "telnet 54.xxx.xxx.13 8088" from your local machine. If it doesn't work then it's a network issue and nothing to do with your application server :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47940/discussion-between-ct-and-909-niklas)

Comment: Hey @DjDacSaunders did you ever resolve your issue here?  I have the same issue with the my server not allowing 8088 to pass through for some strange reason.

Comment: @AdamKlein Try ask it on serverfault because I don't remember how we solved my problem. It _should_ work.